# Error 'Please check your account info and/or permissions and try again.. Client request id: 'undefined''

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am trying go get storage account blob list via azure logic apps. But I am facing this error.

[image]

I tried few things like changing logic app and the storage account into different regions as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-azureblobstorage#problems-accessing-storage-accounts-in-the-same-region).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By digging deeper, I was able to get away from this error by pointing to the right connection.

- Changed the connection
- Point to right connection which you have access for or add a new one.
- If new connection, then enter the proper Azure Storage account name you want to connect with.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I test with set my storage account with allow access from selected networks instead of allow access from all networks, but the "List blobs" action shows "Forbidden" error, it doesn't show the error message `Please check your account infor......` which you mentioned in your question.

But when I create the storage connection manually with incorrect infor(such as a wrong storage name), it shows same error message with yours.

[image]

Unlike your situation, the error message shows when I create the connection in my side but shows in you "List blobs" action. I'm not sure which way did you create the logic app and the storage connection in logic app, so please check if you provide the correct info when you create the logic app and the storage connection.

Comment: Yes, as you said giving the wrong storage account name will also cause the problem. But in my case I was pointing to a wrong connection. I will post an answer with screen shots on how I found solution so that it could help in future